# List of the "Greatest Hits"

Tags: discussion

I just discovered there's a "Greatest Hits" feature build into the site software:

- https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits

I find it remarkable because I don't remember most of these questions, and they're not the questions that are the most upvoted.

Instead they're the ones with the most answers, and/or with the most views.